# Easypost webhook sends lot of 'Unknown' statuses

Tags: php, webhooks, easypost

I have configured a webhook url in easypost, which sends updates whenever a new event occurs in my shipment. I am receiving status as 'unknown' till the day of delivery. Basically, only 2 statuses are received, 'unknown' and 'delivered' (on the delivered date). I am new to easypost. Can anyone help on this?

```php
//webhook function to pick the status from 'Tracker' object
public function update() {

        $data = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);
        
        if(isset($data['result']) && $data['result']['object']=='Tracker') 
        {
            $result = $data['result'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'Unknown' status event should normally only happen once after a tracker is created. If you have some example trackers where this has been a problem, please send them over to support@easypost.com and we would love to look into this more for you. It would also help to know which carrier this is happening with.